# 3 items per row with flexbox and gap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have 3 children per row. When using inline-flex and grid (or margin/padding), the flexbox wraps to 2 children per row. It seems like the grid width is being factored into the width of each child. Without changing the HTML, is there any way to fix this? I would like to keep the same `10px` of spacing between each child, have the parent horizontally centered within the body, and keep each child to a width of `33.3333%`.

The reason I am not just changing it to `flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 10px);` or similar is because this is not an exact solution. The images on the edges of the parent div will not always be `10px` from the edges of the widow.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 10px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS-Grid instead?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-grid;
  width:80%;
  background-color: coral;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.child img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg" style="width: 0;max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to get rid of that small margin at the bottom of each item?

Comment: Set display: flex; for all direct containers of images (div with class "child" in this case)